# Why does an error box with "Virtual Disk Manager | Access is denied." appear when I try to delete Ubuntu partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 16.04, permissions, windows-7

I am trying to uninstall Ubuntu from a dual- boot system with Windows 7. According to the Howtogeek tutorial on this, I need to delete the Ubuntu partitions from the computer. When I side- click them and click "Delete Volume", it gives me a warning box about how the disk has information that may be interpreted by other operating systems and asks if I want to delete the partition. When I click yes, an error box titled "Virtual Disk Manager" with a message saying "Access is denied." appears. According to a few forums on how to solve similar problems with partitions and this error, to solve this, I need to side- click the partition, click "Properties" and change the security settings, but I am not able to click on properties.
[Screenshots](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SDFFN16IFcqfKTwK4KfblBglox070OokaQAeIETF5hM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Did you unmount the drive? Check for that. If that isn't the problem, here's how I'd do it.

In windows there is a command line utility called diskpart. It allows you to manage drives.
Go to your command prompt and type in `diskpart` and give it permission.
Type `list disk` and find the drive by its size.
Type `select disk`- whatever disk number it is.
Now you can use `clean` to wipe the whole drive. If it gives you an error, go to `detail disk` and `select volume` and a volume number. Now you can use `clean`. **MAKE SURE YOU HAVE SELECTED THE CORRECT DRIVE!!!**
You may want to `create partition primary`; `assign letter` with the letter you want the drive to be; and `active`. You should have successfully cleaned your hard drive. Comment with any issues you may have.

In Ubuntu, I use gparted. You can change permissions with `chmod` and maybe even delete them with a terminal with `sudo`. Sorry, not a linux expert yet, but that's what I'd do. :)

Comment: I actually have Ubuntu installed on a partition, not a disk. It is installed on the same disk as all of the other partitions on the computer. I tried using similar instructions to delete a partition, but there were only two partitions labeled "primary" and Diskmgmt shows four (two of which are from Ubuntu).

Comment: Also, I can't mount an Ubuntu partitions, because, as you can see in the screenshots, I can't click "Change Drive Letter and Paths". I don't know if the drive is even mounted, and I can't do anything on Ubuntu, since the mouse and keyboard are unresponsive when I start the computer with it.

Comment: Then at the spot where you select the volume you need to select the correct partition that ubuntu uses. I've never used diskmanagement for wiping drives as it just gets in my way. I guess if you have you you can always make a live usb and get gparted and do it.